# Default Content on failed require_once

Tags: redirect, default, require-once

Just started learning PHP today. And though I moved through most of my problems quickly, I got stumped with this one.

I have a main page page.php with a dynamic require_once to pull up content. I got the main part working, which is page.php?id=1 page.php?id=2 etc load just fine, but if somebody goes to just page.php without the ID, then there are errors that ruin the page. Now I figured out how to repress the errors with an @ and I can also obviously set the links to the page to page?if=default, but I really need a solution to having page.php load content specific to it without errors. Or, perhaps, automatically redirect page.php to page.php?id=default should no id be provided.

The code I current am using for the require_once is:

```
<?php require_once('folder/' .  $_GET['id'] . '.html');?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well easiest way would be to check if you have an ID and if not, than just set default one, something like that:

```
$default = 1;
$id = ($_GET['id'] && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : $default;
require_once('folder/' .  $id . '.html');
```

Comment: Cool, that was super helpful. I am actually using strings, not numerics for many of the id's, and I am calling on multiple content sections per load, so I made some changes. In the header section I added '<?php $default = 'intro';
$id = ($_GET['id'] && is_string($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : $default; ?>' and the different content requests are just the require_once.  Thanks!

Comment: If that helped you, than mark question as answered. And I'm glad i could help.